# How to AutoFill Based on User Data

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have a form for work that requires an employee's name. I have a data validation so we can simply choose from a list, but is there a way to fill the cell automatically, upon opening the file? We each access the company network every time we log onto a company computer, and each of our user data are unique.

[image: Form Cells]

I have the Employee ID set to autofill (via a table and a vlookup) as soon as Driver Name is chosen from the drop-down list, but I would like for users to be able to open the file and have their name autofill based on their user info, thereby also filling the EID so they can print out the sheet more quickly.

If there isn't this kind of functionality in excel, that's fine, I just want to know.

I'm not sure what to put here, because I haven't been able to find anything on google, so I haven't actually tried anything yet. I don't know if it's certain syntax that I need to use (like when saving files to specific domains/folders) or if there's some other included functionality I'm just not aware of.

I'm gonna look up application.username once I get back to work tonight, like @freddy suggested

Comment: Do you mean that you want the user which is currently using Excel? If that is the case perhaps you can use 

`application.username`

Or do you mean something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "set to autofill as soon as Driver Name is chosen"? Do you have a worksheet `Change` event doing that? Or a formula? Something else? Besides that, what "their name and number" does mean? Are the drivers who open the workbook in discussion?

Comment: @FaneDuru the cell for employee ID has a simple excel formula to autofill. "=IF(A1<>"",VLOOKUP(A1,Table1,2,False),"")

Comment: @FreddyMeijer I'm not sure how I'd use that, but I'll give it a google search, thanks for pointing me to a novel keyword 

Comment: Thanks @FreddyMeijer for your comment. It took a bit of digging, but I figured it out. I'll post my answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did:
First, I combined Application.Username with MsgBox to find my username

```
 Sub GetUser()
     MsgBox Application.UserName
 End Sub
```

Then, after realizing that my username was just how we search for people within Outlook, I coded an If-Then statement

```
 Sub IfUserThen()
     If Application.UserName = "EXT-Last, First M" Then
         Range("A!X5").Value = "Last"
     End If
End Sub
```

Then to make it automatic on open, I coded in ThisWorkbook

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Call IfUserThen
 End Sub
```

I have way more names, but didn't list them for sake of brevity.
Thanks for all the help everyone.